# ol3 with Embedded IE11 WebBrowser control(WPF), Mouse click events is not working

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-11, openlayers-3, cesiumjs

I am using **WebBrowser** control in **WPF** application to render Open Street **Maps(osm)** using **ol3(openlayers3)**. It works fine in IE11 browser but mouse events do not work in embedded **IE11 WebBrowser Control**. If I make my WebBrowser to Emulate IE10, then mouse events are fired but 3d view (Cesium) does not work.

I am using http://openlayers.org/ol3-cesium/examples/main.html as an example. I am hosting it locally on python server and rendering it in WebBrowser control. To run WebGL and Cesium I have modified **FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION** key to 11000 and **FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING** key to 1 of my **.exe**

I want to use IE11 as I need to render 3d globe view of the map using ol3-Cesium. All the mouse click events work fine in the 3d globe view, but when I disable the 3d view and enable 2d view, mouse events do not fire. I am not sure if I am missing some change in registry.

I also followed [ol3 with IE11 in a c# webbrowser control mouse click events not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752190/ol3-with-ie11-in-a-c-sharp-webbrowser-control-mouse-click-events-not-working)  but I am not satisfied with the answer. It is recommending to use Chromium as few events does not work with IE11. But if 3d globe view is allowing the events to fire then why not 2d in ol3. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In the registry, turn on `FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING`, and turn off compatibility mode by setting `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` to 0.

This code worked for me.  Most answers I found suggested setting `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` to the latest IE version on your machine but that never worked with Cesium.  Setting it to 0, i.e. turning off compatibility mode did work.

```
    internal static void SetBrowserFeaturesToSupportGpu()
          {
             // FeatureControl settings are per-process
             var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName( Process.GetCurrentProcess( ).MainModule.FileName );
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_96DPI_PIXEL",
             fileName,
             1)
             ; // enable hi-dpi support
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
             fileName,
             00000)
             ; // turn off compatibility mode.
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_AJAX_CONNECTIONEVENTS",
             fileName,
             1)
             ;
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_ENABLE_CLIPCHILDREN_OPTIMIZATION",
             fileName,
             1)
             ;
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING",
             fileName,
             1)
             ; // use GPU rendering
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_IVIEWOBJECTDRAW_DMLT9_WITH_GDI  ",
             fileName,
             0)
             ; // force directX
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE",
             fileName,
             0)
             ;
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS",
             fileName,
             1)
             ;
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION",
             fileName,
             1)
             ;
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_SPELLCHECKING",
             fileName,
             0)
             ;
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_STATUS_BAR_THROTTLING",
             fileName,
             1)
             ;
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_VALIDATE_NAVIGATE_URL",
             fileName,
             1)
             ;
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_WEBOC_DOCUMENT_ZOOM",
             fileName,
             1)
             ; // allow zoom.
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_WEBOC_POPUPMANAGEMENT",
             fileName,
             0)
             ; // disallow auto-popups
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_ADDON_MANAGEMENT",
             fileName,
             0)
             ; // disallow auto-addons/plugins
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_WEBSOCKET",
             fileName,
             1)
             ;
             SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(
             "FEATURE_WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS",
             fileName,
             0)
             ; // disallow popups
          }


internal static void SetBrowserFeatureControlKey( string feature, string appName, uint value )
      {
         using ( var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
             String.Concat( @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\", feature ),
             RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree ) )
         {
            key.SetValue( appName, ( UInt32 ) value, RegistryValueKind.DWord );
         }
      }
```

Comment: The webbrowser control is now smother